# How to check whcich package is set as startup in a SSIS project in SSDT VS2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

In SQL Server Data Tools for VS 2015, how can I check which of my SSIS packages has been set as the startup package of my project. I'm not able to find a setting/property that confirms that. I know that to set a package as "startup package", one will just right-click on the package and select "Startup .."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on the Solution folder
2. Click on Properties
3. Click on Configuration Properties
4. Go To Debugging
5. Click on Start Action
6. Set the start object id to Active Package

[image]